# Python cv2.imshow works correctly but cv2.imwrite saves black image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to use a bit mask to cut out an object from a JPG image to a 4 channel PNG image that has transparent background. It shows correctly when I show the result with cv2.imshow, but show a black image if I save it with cv2.imwrite.

Example:

Here is the original image

[image]

Here is the mask

[image]

Here is the correct result that cv2.imshow() shows

[image]

Here is the code

```
# read the original jpg image
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# create an empty 2d numpy array with zeros with the shape of the original image
arraymask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)

# poly_cords is an list with polygon coordinates for the mask
# create a numpy array from the polygon list
polynumpy = np.array(poly_cords, dtype=np.int32)

# fill the the zero 2d image with the polygon shape to create the mask image shown above
arraymask = cv2.fillPoly(arraymask, [polynumpy], color=255)

# create empty transparent image with 4 channels filled with zeros
transparent_im = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 4), dtype=np.uint8)

# fill up first 3 channels with only the part of the image that is the shape of the mask
transparent_im[arraymask == 255, :3] = image[arraymask == 255]

cv2.imshow("help", transp_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite("image.png", transp_image)
```

Solution:

I forgot to fill up the alpha layer.

```
transparent_im[arraymask == 255, 3] = 255
```

Comment: "create empty transparent image with 4 channels filled with zeros" .... and you never change the alpha channel -- alpha of zero is fully transparent. And `imshow` ignores alpha, that's why you can see something. Whatever program you're using to view `image.png` doesn't ignore alpha, and since you made your whole image completely transparent, you can't see any of it.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you. Now i get it!